# Mixing two sounds in ffmpeg going wrong

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I've come across a certain problem and couldn't find a solution anywhere, so:

I have two files, f1.mp3 which is a common mp3 file, some sounds that's all, and f2.mp3 which is mostly silence but has one part with some sound in the middle of it. Both files are 1 minute long. The problem is that when I try to merge it I get the f1.mp3 volume lower. This process is repeated several times so in result first sounds get completely silent. How can I do it without this issue? Currently I've tested this two instructions:

```
ffmpeg -i f1.mp3 -i f2.mp3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first out.mp3
```

and

```
ffmpeg -i f1.mp3 -i f2.mp3 -filter_complex \"[0:a][1:a]amerge[aout]\" -map \"[aout]\" -ac 2 out.mp3
```

Comment: Please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output from each command.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm facing the exact same problem. And if I follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/38714779/3598052 this then volume gets louder each time I run command.

Answer (score 1):

As `amix` is intended to maintain the same max volume as the inputs to prevent clipping, it normalizes audio prior to mixing (thus, `amixing` the same two inputs would render the same output instead of increasing it's volume). If you need the original volume of both inputs adding up, you must apply a `volume` filter:

```
ffmpeg -i f1.mp3 -i f2.mp3 -filter_complex '[0][1] amix=inputs=2:duration=first [a];[a] volume=volume=2 [b]' -map [b] out.mp3
```

Note that if you need more than two audios, you would need to apply the correspoding gain.

**Note: ouput could be clipped because of that second filter, check result!**